# What namespace or facade do I have to use in Laravel to have access to my models inside a namespaced class?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, eloquent

I'm totally new to namespaces, and Laravel in general, so their use of Facades complicates the issue a bit for me.

I have set up a class that is namespaced:

```
namespace Libraries;
class UploadedFile {
}
```

(As there is already a Symfony class uploadedFile), and now in that class I need to use one of my models, which I can only assume rests somewhere under the `Eloquent` facade, yet if I:

```
use Eloquent;
```

and

```
use \Eloquent;
```

in my class, I am told my model cannot be found, yet if I prepend my model with a backslash directly:

```
return \Object::create(...);
```

It works perfectly fine. What do I need to `use` at the top of my namespaced file to include access to my models directly without the need for a slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eloquent` has nothing to do with this. You have to import your actual model `Object`:

```
use Object;
```